# Can't get button to appear using Tkinter in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a pretty simple Python Tkinter question that I can't figure out.  I have typed in the following lines of code:

```
from Tkinter import *     
tk = Tk()   
btn = Button(tk, text = "click me")   
btn.pack()
```

According to the book I'm using, a button should appear on the screen but it doesn't.  I'm trying to teach middle schoolers to code in Python so I'm not experienced, but would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you're just learning, I suggest _not_ importing tkinter the way most tutorials show. Instead, use `import Tkinter as tk` and then prefix all tk-related items with `tk.` (eg: `tk.Tk()`, `tk.Button`, etc). For more on why you should not use `*` in an import see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the main loop. Add this to the bottom:

```
tk.mainloop()
```